# ldapsearch and SRV RRs

Tags: openldap

I am attempting and failing to use `ldapsearch` (or any of the other [`openldap utilities`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ldap-utils)) with DNS SRV Resource Records. However, I believe it should be [possible](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release) and that I am using the proper [syntax](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch14/#ldapsearch).

How do I use ldapsearch with DNS SRV RRs?

---

```
$ dig -t srv _ldap._tcp.example.com +short
0 0 389 ldap1.example.com.
0 0 389 ldap2.example.com.
$ ldapsearch -H "dc=example,dc=com" uid=test
Could not parse LDAP URI(s)=dc=example,dc=com
$ ldapsearch -H "ldap:///dc=example,dc=com" uid=test
Could not parse LDAP URI(s)=ldap:///dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: Does it work if you escape the ldap uri ? `ldapsearch -H ldap:///dc%3Dexample%2Cdc%3Dcom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Escape the ldap uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) like this:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap:///dc%3Dexample%2Cdc%3Dcom
```